# Serial COM Port not opening

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port

I am trying to open the serial COM PORT in a Win32 Application. The port is opening correctly but I can send a receive bytes just if I previously opened it using Teraterm or Hyperterminal.

If I deactivate and activate the COM port from Device Manager (so the port is freshly unused) I need to simply open the COM port with Teraterm or Putty and afer I closed it  and then run my software I can send and receive properly at anytime.

I am using Embarcadero X3 with FileMonkey to make the application compatible with MACOSX and Win32 at the same time. FileMonkey does not suuport VCL.

The same code is working fine on Builder 6 c++ using VCL but it should not influence it in anyway. My code is really simple.

This is a very weird behavior. Seems like I need to INIT the COM (I am using FTDI converter) before I can use it and when the PC restarts or I deactivate and activate back the COM from Device Manager it seems this INIT is vanished and I simply need to open up the COM to revive it using another Serial Software and then use my software.

Note: Once the port is INIT I have the full control from my software. I am sure my code is truly opening the COM port because the COM appears busy once the iNIT is done if I try to use it with other softwares. So no flase alarm and more the application is working on the other side so far.

I have this problem since long and I now decided to solve it!

This is my code:

```
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
HANDLE hComm = NULL;
COMMTIMEOUTS ctmoNew = {0}, ctmoOld;

DCB dcbCommPort; 
      hComm = CreateFile("COM2",

                      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                      0,
                      0,
                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                      0,
                      0);

    if(hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
     {

        Application->Terminate();
     }

    GetCommTimeouts(hComm,&ctmoOld);
    ctmoNew.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;
    ctmoNew.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    ctmoNew.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    ctmoNew.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &ctmoNew);
    dcbCommPort.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
    GetCommState(hComm, &dcbCommPort);
    BuildCommDCB("115200,N,8,1", &dcbCommPort);
    SetCommState(hComm, &dcbCommPort);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a possibility, not certain that this is the problem.

But one difference to our typical COM port opening code is that we use [SetupCom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363439(v=vs.85).aspx) directly after the CreateFile succeeded and set our buffer sizes, typically 4KB.

Answer (score 0):

Change your settings to:

"115200,NOPARITY,8,ONESTOPBIT"